# Append date to filename before copy in php

Tags: php, string, copy

I am trying to append date to the file name before copying in PHP.

```
$fileS = "file.csv";
$date = date('m-d-Y H:i:s A e');
$fileD = "file$date.csv";
```

I have even tried

```
$fileD = "file"."date('m-d-Y H:i:s A e')".".csv";
```

Then I copy the files

```
$Confirm = copy($fileS, $fileD);
```

I know I should check if the file exists etc etc but for the sake of simplicity to ask the question I am using this :).

I am assuming it's something to do with the copy function that doesn't read concatenated strings. I may be wrong here.

Any help with this is great appreciated.

EDIT: The colon seems to be the problem not the $fileD. Any type of concatenation would work. (Thanks to Greenisha).

This one works but any ideas to make it work with the colon. It seems weird to have the time with '-' instead of ':'.

```
$date = date('m-d-Y H-i-s A e');
```

Never mind. Colons are not allowed in the file naming convention in windows. Overlooked that part. Thanks Michael.

I am creating this in windows now but when it goes to production it will be in in UNIX. So will the colon work there if I change it? Any suggestion will be useful down the road. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What OS?  Are colons allowed in filenames?  I don't think Windows allows them, for example.

Comment: Choose a different date format and try it. Maybe 'm-d-Y-His'

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try it using a date format that doesn't include colons.  Colons are not permitted in Windows filenames, and perhaps other filesystem types.

```
// Try, for example
$fileD = "file".date('m-d-Y-His A e').".csv";
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I see, your problem is because of identifier:

```
e Timezone identifier (added in PHP 5.1.0) Examples: UTC, GMT, Atlantic/Azores
```

But filename can't be with "/" inside. Try using another date format

Comment: I don't think that's the problem but I tried what you suggested and it still doesn't work. I changed the date to date('m-d-Y H:i:s A').

Comment: yea the colon seems to be the problem...php doesn't like the colon for some reason

Answer (score 2):

You know, I'm always wary of putting spaces in file names, call it a throwback to the 80's and 90's. What happens if you just try:

```
var_dump(preg_replace('-\W-','_',date('m-d-Y H:i:s A e')));
```

Comment: nostalgy.  You are not the only one who avoids spaces.  It's a good practice and saves time to not have to worry about escaping spaces all over the code.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:
    `$fileD = "file".$date.".csv";`

Or:
    `$fileD = "file{$date}.csv";`

Answer (score 1):

When you concatenate a statement (such as your date function) it should not be surrounded by quotes.  So your second example should work written like so:

```
$fileD = "file".date('m-d-Y H:i:s A e').".csv";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this utility function:

```
public static function appendDateTimeToFileName($fileName) {
    $appended = date('_Y_m_d_H_i_s');
    $dotCount = substr_count($fileName, '.');
    if (!$dotCount) {
        return $fileName . $appended;
    }
    $extension = pathinfo($fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $fileName = pathinfo($fileName, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
    return $fileName . $appended . '.' . $extension;
}
```

Example:

```
sample.jpg  -> sample_2017_02_19_01_09_10.jpg
sample      -> sample_2017_02_19_01_09_44
```