# use php date in href filename

Tags: php, date, anchor, filenames

I'm a designer/front-end developer just getting into PHP, so it's all still very new to me, so forgive the stupid simple questions. :)

I'm wanting to use php to generate a date for a filename in an html anchor.  The end result I need:

```
<a href="url.com/filepath/name-2013-06.pdf">text</a>
```

Where year and month are generated by php.

Brace yourself... This is what I've tried:

```
<a href="url.com/filepath/name-<?php echo date('Y-m');?>.pdf">text</a>
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Your date call is correct, so what's the issue?

Comment: Brandon, this question needs a little improvement. It is not clear what you are actually asking. Are you receiving errors? Is it behaving in an unexpected way? Throw us a bone, here.

Comment: This is the result I get in the browser URL:"url.com/filepath/name-%3C?php%20echo%20date(%22Y-m%22);?%3E.pdf" and it's not reaching the file.

Comment: BTW, I'm using rackspace cloud for hosting the file.

Comment: Brandon, the file isn't being interpreted as a php file. Is the file extension .html or .php? Does your hosting support php?

Comment: The file is .pdf and our our host supports PHP (we're using WordPress just fine).

Comment: I believe @JonathanFingland was referring to the file in which you make a call to PHP's `echo`. The most likely cause of the problem is that your server does not support PHP, or the file is not saved as a .php

Edit: for a call as mundane as an echo, I would use <?= ?> for your tags. they're the same as saying <? echo "..." ?>

Comment: Brandon, the file you are referring to is .pdf, but where is the <?php ?> being used? Is it being used inside of wordpress' post editor?

Comment: I think you'll first need to define a `date...` variable, then use its variable in the echo'ed filename, same as you would for an renamed uploaded file for instance.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood.  The file is a .php.  It's hosted inside the WP file structure, but not in a template page (I'm testing it with just the above link on a page, nothing else).

Comment: What are you using to edit the file? Open it in a plaint text editor and look at that part. (If you're using something like dreamweaver, then there will be a way to view the raw code which would also work)

Comment: @Brandon Check this link out on SO, may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6444646/append-date-to-filename-before-copy-in-php

Comment: @Fred, you're trying to answer a different question. He's trying to create an href that includes the date, not the file itself (yet)

Comment: @JonathanFingland It was a `reference`, and one that is useful at best.

Comment: @Brandon There are 2 options for you below, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Based on OP [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16907324/use-php-date-in-href-filename#comment24401991_16907324)

> This is the result I get in the browser URL:"url.com/filepath/name-%3C?php%20echo%20date(%22Y-m%22);?%3E.pdf" and it's not reaching the file.

It would appear that the file is not actually being interpreted as a PHP file and is being sent as plain text.

Possible causes:

- File is .html, .htm, .txt or other plain text extension.
- Host does not support PHP either through  missing or insufficient mime type handling, or not actually having PHP installed.

Comment: That's what I though.  But the file is PHP (with .php ext) and is being hosted on the same sever as a fully-functioning wp installation (which requires PHP).

Turns out it was a combination of an old php redirect I had commented out that was interfering and some pesky browser caching.  I removed it completely, cleared the cache and it's working now.

And I'm guessing HTML comments don't affect PHP? Thank you all for your help - when you confirmed my execution was correct, I started looking elsewhere.

Comment: Yeah, PHP statements execute regardless of HTML comments. So, for example <!-- <?php echo "TEST"; ?> --> would actually result in <!-- TEST -->. You'll occasionally see sites that output things like script execution time in a comment at the end of a page.

Answer (score 1):

**Here, give this a whirl. (tested)**

I'm sure there probably are a few more ways to achieve this, but it works.

```
<?php

$file = date('Y-m').".pdf";

?>
```

**Using this link format/syntax (inside the same file):**

```
<a href="http://url.com/filepath/name-<?php echo $file; ?>">text</a>
```

**Result is:**

`http://url.com/filepath/name-2013-06.pdf`

---

---

***You can also try:***

```
<a href="http://url.com/filepath/name-<?php echo date('Y-m') . ".pdf";?>">text</a>
```

**Result is:**

`http://url.com/filepath/name-2013-06.pdf`

As per your original question.